Check if dates fall between a selected week in apps script
I've managed to make this script that copies and pastes data into a history sheet then deletes those rows out of the first sheet. It's set to trigger every Saturday morning and also by a button. I now want it to check if either of the dates in columns C and D fall between the dates set in A1 and B1 (this will be the first date of the selected week in A1 and the last date in B1) and only copy the rows that don't match.
How do I get it to check the if either column matches?
Here's the script I'm working with:
function clearschedule() {
  
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var schedSheet = s.getSheetByName("Schedule Setup");
var histSheet = s.getSheetByName("Schedule History");
var ssLastRow = schedSheet.getLastRow();
var hsLastRow = histSheet.getLastRow();
var rowcount = schedSheet.getRange('I1').getValue();
var schlog = schedSheet.getRange(3,1,ssLastRow,8).getValues();
var histss = histSheet.getRange(hsLastRow + 1,1,ssLastRow,8);
var schrng = schedSheet.getRange(3,1,ssLastRow,8);

histSheet.insertRowsAfter(hsLastRow + 1,rowcount);
histss.setValues(schlog);
schrng.clearContent();

}

This script works perfectly to remove all rows, but I'm trying to only remove the rows where the dates in column C or D don't match and keep the ones that do. These dates are from and to dates so they might not both fall in the same week which is why I need it to check if either column matches.

Hi and Welcome, Would you be able to provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you. You may use this anonymous sheet maker to create your reproducible example without your email being exposed.

Hi, here's a dummy copy of the sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F4vHr7zzxc3YQiqTISPcqBqW8lE8LROOO5Vq2pvwTRs/edit?usp=sharing

Modified script using Append row and Delete row.
The condition checks if the end date is before the start date from A1 or if the start date is after the end date from B1. If either condition is true, the row is appended to the Schedule History sheet.
This is what I Modified on the Script.
function clearschedule() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Schedule Setup');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Schedule History');
  var dateFromSheet1 = new Date(sheet1.getRange('A1').getValue());
  var dateToSheet1 = new Date(sheet1.getRange('B1').getValue());
  var data = sheet1.getRange(3, 1, sheet1.getLastRow() - 2, sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  
  
  for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var rowDateFrom = new Date(data[i][2]);  
    var rowDateTo = data[i][3];  
  
    if (!rowDateTo) {
      rowDateTo = rowDateFrom;
      sheet1.getRange(i + 3, 4).setValue(rowDateFrom);  
    } else {
      rowDateTo = new Date(rowDateTo);  
    }
    
    if (rowDateTo < dateFromSheet1 || rowDateFrom > dateToSheet1) {
      sheet2.appendRow([data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2], rowDateTo, data[i][4], data[i][5], data[i][6], data[i][7]]);
      sheet1.deleteRow(i + 3);
    }
  }
}

Sample Output
Highlighted should be moved in Schedule history

Result once the button is clicked.
Schedule Setup

Schedule History

Reference

appendRow(rowContents)
deleteRow(rowPosition)

